# Segmentation Fault in loops C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm running into a problem here with segmentation faults.

Here is the code:

```
string CipherMessage::VigDecipher(string key)
{
    int keyValue;
    int charValue;
    string textInit = m_text;

    // Initializes an array containing the alphabet. A=index 0, B=index 1, etc
    string alphabet[26] = "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"\
                           "P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    // keyValues contains the values of each term of the multi-character key.
    int keyValues[6];

    // Enters the keyValues into the array.
    for (int i=0; i<key.length(); i++){
        for (int j=0; i<=25; j++){
            if (key[i] == ALPHABET[j])
                keyValues[i] = j;
        }
    }
    return m_text_new;
}
```

It just gives me the segmentation fault.

Comment: There's a significant number of basic syntax errors in the posted code.

Comment: more than the i that's supposed to be j?

Comment: This line: `string alphabet[26] = ...` will not even remotely compile.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized something went wrong when I was copying it in here.

Comment: Thanks though! It helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that this line is the problem:

```
for (int j=0; i<=25; j++){
```

Note that the character `i` is not the character `j`.

Comment: Jeez.  -.- This is embarassing.  I've spent the last hour not noticing this.

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty: Situations like this are a great time to learn how to use a debugger. A debugger would very quickly show you that the value of `j` was well outside your expected range when the segmentation fault occured.

Comment: Where can I find that out?

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty: It would vary based on what platform / ide you use. Many IDEs have embedded debuggers. Visual Studio does for example. On a Linux command line I've often used gdb or lldb.

Comment: @MichaelDaugherty Unless you are averse to Microsoft, I suggest you download their Visual Studio Express Edition which has an excellent C++ debugger. Once your code is working locally, you can then try it on your university's server.

Comment: I use windows regularly, but we do our work on the server.  I will definitely look into it @NeilKirk.